# ceph configure mount vie using fstab

Tags: ceph, fstab

i have successfully mounted ceph using the command:

```
mount -t ceph ceph-mon1.storage:6789:/ /mnt/mycephfs -o name=cephx,secretfile=/etc/ceph/ceph.client.cephx.keyring
```

but when i try to set it persistent vis fstab it does not work

```
ceph ceph-mon1.storage:6789:/ /mnt/ftd ceph name=cephx,secretfile=/etc/ceph/ceph.client.cephx.keyring,noatime 0 0
```

i am based on https://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/cephfs/kernel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my mistake, needed to remove ceph from beginning
ceph-mon1.storage:6789:/ /mnt/ftd ceph name=cephx,secretfile=/etc/ceph/ceph.client.cephx.keyring,noatime 0 0